# Redirecting to mobile page in Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, redirecttoaction

I'm trying to use a different login page for an Asp.Net MVC application that is modified to fit mobile devices, primarily iPhone/Android. All I basically need is to modify the login view, because the actual content is in a particular part of the application, I'm not trying to make a mobile version of the entire site.

So I tried to follow this: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

But I don't know the authentication well enough to know exactly how to do the logon action methods for the mobile version. I feel like I'm probably missing a specific mobile post action,and I don't understand what to do with the url passed in the redirect. Here's what I've got so far:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            if ((returnUrl != null) && returnUrl.StartsWith("/Mobile/",
                                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("LogOnMobile", "Account",
                                        new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LogOnMobile(string returnurl)
        {
            return View();

        }



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

And this doesn't work. I get to the mobile login page (or actually so far I've just tried out that the action method works by commenting out the if clause), but when I try to login I just get to the same page again, but strangely without the fields...

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Do you keep the account controller in the Mobile Area? Better practice will be using the mobile Area to keep all your mobile site stuff and redirect the authorization to the AccountController.

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        if ((returnUrl != null) && returnUrl.StartsWith("/Mobile/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { Area = "Mobile", ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

        return ContextDependentView();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere you are actually checking to see if it is a mobile device to re-direct:

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){ }
```

Comment: Well, according to the Microsoft page I referred to, the url string check for "/Mobile/" is supposed to do that...

Comment: The check for "/Mobile/" is fine, but a mobile browser will not add that to your request url automatically.  You have to check if it is a mobile browser first, and then add the "Mobile" to the url.  Read through the document again.  the "Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice()" call is where you are actually checking if the request came from a mobile browser or not.  I am sure that it is just checking the user-agent string in the http request.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that might come in handy anyway then, but still it's not an answer to my actual question. Like I mentioned, I have commented out the if test, just to try the methods, and even if I get to the correct GET method, I don't know how to move on from there. It seems to get stuck there.